# Alterando MySQL com ajax e PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Criei um sistema que o usuario consegue visualizar dados de um banco de dados mysql e, eventualmente, interagir com esses dados (alterando através de um `select` a coluna `status` no banco de dados). Atualmente existe um script php que é executado quando o usuário seleciona o novo status e clica em um botão que da o submit.

**O problema**

Após o usuário selecionar o novo status e der submit, é necessário que ele atualize a pagina para ver o novo status, o que é bem chato.

Consegui criar o AJAX para que ele pegue os dados desse campo (a checkbox que tras a id da linha e o valor do campo `select`) e ambos os valores estão sendo enviados assim pelo ajax:

```
Object {changePedi: "separacao", checkbox: "256"} // checkbox é o valor da id no mysql
```

**A pergunta**

Como adaptar o antigo código php (que agora esta em um arquivo chamado `status.php` para ele trabalhar com esses dados? Abaixo as configurações que estou usando, mas não esta funcionando

*index.php* (onde estão o select e onde é gerada as tabelas para o usuário)

```
<div id="statusPedidos">
<label>Selecione o status:</label>
<select id="changePed">
    <option value="separacao">Em Separação</option>
    <option value="separado">Separado</option>
    <option value="faturado">Faturado</option>
    <option value="exp">Expedido</option>
    <option value="entrg">Mercadoria Entregue</option>
    <option value="cancelado">Cancelado</option>            
</select>
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" onclick="altera_status()">Alterar</button>                        
<div id="myDiv"><table id='pedidos' class='table table-hover table-responsive'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type='checkbox' name='select-all' id='select-all' /></th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>EMS</th>
            <th>Pedido do  cliente</th>
            <th>Cliente</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
            <th>Aut. Comercial</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Nota Fiscal</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php
    $vaziodata = date("Y-m-d");
    $mes = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 week"));
    $resultFIL = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `pedidos` WHERE `emissaoPed` BETWEEN '$mes' AND '$vaziodata' "); 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultFIL))
    {
        $dataped = $row['emissaoPed'];
        $valorped = $row['vlr'];
        echo "<tbody><tr>";
        echo "<td><input class='checkped' name='checkbox[]' type='checkbox' value=" . $row['id'] . "></td>";
        echo "<td>" . date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dataped)) . "</td>";
        echo "<td><a id='ver_pedido' data-ref=".$row['nPedido']." data-toggle='modal' id='abremodal' href='#myModal'>" . $row['nPedido'] . "</a></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['NrPedido'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['nomeAbrev'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . number_format($valorped, 2, ',', '.') . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='button' value='Autorizado' name='autCom' ></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' placeholder='0012345' style='width: 70px; id='nfd';>&nbsp<button class='btn btn-success' type='submit' onclick='att_nf()'><i class='fa fa-check' aria-hidden='true'></i></button></td> ";
        echo "</tr></tbody>";

    }
    echo "</table>";

    ?>
```

Este é o script do ajax que envia e recebe os dados

```
function altera_status()
{
var checkboxValues = $.map($('.checkped:checked'), function(e){
    return $(e).val();
}).join();
//dados a enviar, vai buscar os valores dos campos que queremos enviar para a BD
var dadosajax = {
    'changePedi' : $("#changePed").val(),
    'checkbox' : checkboxValues,

};
console.log(dadosajax), 
pageurl = 'status.php';
//para consultar mais opcoes possiveis numa chamada ajax
//http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
$.ajax({

    //url da pagina
    url: pageurl,
    //parametros a passar
    data: dadosajax,
    //tipo: POST ou GET
    type: 'POST',
    //cache
    cache: false,
    //se ocorrer um erro na chamada ajax, retorna este alerta
    //possiveis erros: pagina nao existe, erro de codigo na pagina, falha de comunicacao/internet, etc etc etc
    error: function(){
        alert('Erro: Inserir Registo!!');
    },
    //retorna o resultado da pagina para onde enviamos os dados
    success: function(response)
    { 

    }
});
}
```

*status.php* (para onde vão as informações enviadas pelo ajax e onde são executadas as query's)

```
 <?php  

     $_REQUEST['changePedi'] = $statusPed;
     $_REQUEST['checkbox'] = $checkStatus; 

     echo $checkStatus;


     $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "notas-34ca74") or die ("Forninho fall"); 



     switch($_REQUEST['changePedi']){
        case 'separacao':
        function filter( $dados ){
            $arr = Array();
            foreach( $dados AS $dado ) $arr[] = (int)$dado;
            return $arr;
        }     
        if(isset($_REQUEST['checkbox'])){
            $arr = filter($_REQUEST['checkbox']);
            $sql = 'UPDATE pedidos SET status="Em separação" WHERE id IN('.implode( ',', $arr ).')';
            $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        }
        break;
        case 'cancelado':
        function filter( $dados ){
            $arr = Array();
            foreach( $dados AS $dado ) $arr[] = (int)$dado;
            return $arr;
        }     
        if(isset($_REQUEST['checkbox'])){
            $arr = filter( $_REQUEST['checkbox']);
            $sql = 'UPDATE pedidos SET status="Cancelado" WHERE id IN('.implode( ',', $arr ).')';
            $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
        }
        break;
```